# Searchkick - how to show all similar results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchkick

I have records, "Pharrell Williams", "Will Smith", "will.i.am".
When i put for example : `Artist.search("will")` I want to see all of them.
I've tried suggestions, and with `misspellings: { edit_distance: 5 }` but I only get 'Will Smith' out.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
class Artist < ApplicationRecord
  searchkick word_start: [:name]
...
```

And then

```
Artist.search 'will', fields: ['name'], match: :word_start
```

should return all 3 results.